# Why does $\cos\left(\frac13\arctan(\frac{11}2)\right) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$?

Tags: trigonometry

Why does $\cos\left(\frac13\arctan(\frac{11}2)\right) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$?

I couldn't figure out out to apply trig rules so that I can solve this myself. Without the $\frac13$ this makes intuitive sense what's going on but with the $\frac13$ I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: You need to determine the value of $\cos (\frac 13 \alpha)$, knowing that $\tan \alpha = \frac{11}{2}$.

Comment: Follow up from the previous comment : from $\tan \alpha$, find $\sec \alpha$ and then $\cos \alpha$. Then use the triple angle formula to find $\cos(\frac 13\alpha)$.

Comment: In $cos(\frac{\alpha}{3})$, we know $tan\alpha=\frac{11}{2}$ which implies $cos\alpha=\frac{2}{\sqrt {125}}$, follow the previous comment

Comment: I get $4u^3 - 3u - \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}=0.\ $ where $u=\alpha/3.$ Other than cheating and using my calculator to solve cubic equations, how do I solve this? Or does the method in the previous questions avoid this?

Comment: @AdamRubinson Let $y = u\sqrt{5}$, rephrase the equation in terms of $y$ and use the rational root theorem.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can proceed as follows.

Let $\tan 3x = \frac{11}{2}$

So $\tan^{-1}\frac{11}{2}=3x$

Substitute this in the expression.

You get your expression as $\cos x$

Now, you have
$$\tan 3x = \frac{11}{2}$$
$$\frac{3\tan x - \tan^3 x}{1 - 3\tan^2 x} = \frac{11}{2}$$
Put $\tan x = z$

Simplify the equation to bring it in standard form

$$2z^3-33z^2-6z+11=0$$
$$(2z-1)(z^2-16z-11)=0$$
$$z=\frac{1}{2},8 + 5\sqrt{3}, 8 - 5\sqrt{3}$$
Considering the root $\frac{1}{2}$
$$\tan x = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\cos x = \frac{1}{\sec x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 x}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4}}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.